# Inverse image - direct image adjunction

Tags: sheaf-theory, adjoint-functors, functors, presheaves

I've been struggling to prove the adjunction between the inverse image and direct image functors for sheaves, and am looking to find either a reference/book that explains it, suggestions for an alternate proof strategy, or a sketch of a proof.

Using the fact that sheafification is left adjoint to the inclusion functor from pre-sheaves to sheaves, it suffices to show that the inverse image functor for presheaves is left adjoint to the direct image functor for presheaves. So for $f:X\to Y$ let $f^{-1}:\mathrm{Psh(Y)}\to \mathrm{Psh}(X)$ be given by $f^{-1}(\mathcal{F})(U)=\mathrm{colim}_{V\supseteq f(U)}\mathcal{G}(V)$ and let $f_*:\mathrm{Psh(X)}\to \mathrm{Psh}(Y)$ given by $f_*(\mathcal{F})(U)=\mathcal{F}(f^{-1}(U))$ be the standard direct image functor. We can construct a unit $\eta:1\Rightarrow f_*f^{-1}$ and a counit $\epsilon:f^{-1}f_*\to 1$ for the hypothetical adjunction $f^{-1}\vdash f_*$ so that
$$\eta_{\mathcal{G}}(U):\mathcal{G}(U)\to \mathrm{colim}_{V\supseteq f(f^{-1}(U))}\mathcal{G}(V)=f_*f^{-1}\mathcal{G}(U)$$
and
$$\epsilon_{\mathcal{F}}(U):f^{-1}f_*\mathcal{F}(U)=\mathrm{colim}_{V\supseteq f(U)}\mathcal{F}(f^{-1}(V))
\to \mathcal{F}(U)
$$
are the maps one might expect. I've trying to prove the adjunction by proving the triangle identities $\epsilon f^{-1}\circ f^{-1}\eta=1$ and $f_*\epsilon\circ \eta f_*=1.$ I think I more or less understand the argument for this step, but unfortunately it seems quite nasty and difficult to get a good handle on.

Can anyone point me to a good reference that writes this out in detail? Another proof strategy I considered is explicity showing that the map $\mathrm{Hom}(f^{-1}\mathcal{G},\mathcal{F})\to \mathrm{Hom}(\mathcal{G},f_*\mathcal{F})$ given by $\phi\mapsto f_*\phi\circ \eta_G$ is both a surjection and an injection, or something like that. Would that be easier? Is there another way to do it? Perhaps we could first construct a left adjoint to $f_*$ and then show later that it takes the appropriate form? I appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: How about giving an explicit inverse $\operatorname{Hom}(X, f_* Y) \to \operatorname{Hom}(f^{-1} X, Y)$ and then you just need to verify the two compositions are the identity?  That would look something like: given $\varphi : X \to f_* Y$, induce a map $f^{-1} X(U) \to Y(U)$ by the compatible family $X(V) \to Y(U), x \mapsto \varphi(V)(x) |_U$ for each $V \supseteq f(U)$; then check the compatibility comdition, and that it commutes with restrictions for $U' \subseteq U$, etc.

Comment: Given the uniqueness of inverses, if you can show the compositions work out, then the inverse I give will have to agree with $\psi \mapsto \varepsilon \circ f^{-1} \psi$.  But by "abstracting" somewhat you can avoid needing to think about iterations of $f_* f^{-1} f_*$ or $f^{-1} f_* f^{-1}$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Your suggestion worked out thanks!